# how to sort and clean up a text file?

Tags: command-line, sort

I have massive text file with stupid data in it like "BR" (the BR had greater than/less than signs on either side of it, i have already removed the BR from the file, it just need it sorted neat line by line and remove duplicates.
i need to take all the data, each line to have its very own single x.y.z domain per line
taking the lines with spaces and moving them to there own lines.

**so if you have like already:**

```
/temp/>$ cat temp.txt
 
243.abb.com  www.243.abb.com  mypassword.abb.com
pdc.owc.abb.com   pdc.owc.test.abb.com   pdc.template.abb.com   pdc.template.dev.abb.com
etc...
```

```
/temp/$> some-kind-of-script-tosort.sh temp.txt  
 (this creates a new file temp.new.txt)
```

**you make it look like this:**

```
/temp/>$  cat temp.new.txt

243.abb.com
www.243.abb.com
mypassword.abb.com
pdc.owc.abb.com
pdc.owc.test.abb.com
pdc.template.abb.com
pdc.template.dev.abb.com
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us what's actually in the file (`od -bc file.txt` will show each and every byte), I'll assume nothing but spaces between the entries.

```
tr ' ' "\n" file.txt | grep -Ev '^$'
```

This works by changing all the spaces to newlines (`LF`,0x0), then eliminating all the empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. use `grep -o` to output each sequence of non-blank characters on a separate line:

   ```
    grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+' temp.txt > temp.new.txt
   ```
2. use awk, with sequences of whitespace as the input record separator

   ```
    awk 1 RS='[[:space:]]+' temp.txt > temp.new.txt
   ```
3. use awk with the default input separators, but set the output field separator to a newline (kind of the awk implementation of #1)

   ```
    awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\n' temp.txt > temp.new.txt
   ```
4. use sed to replace sequences of blank characters with newlines:

   ```
    sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\n/g' temp.txt > temp.new.txt
   ```
5. (probably the most efficient) replace whitespace with newlines, squeezing repeats

   ```
    tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < temp.txt > temp.new.txt
   ```